# How can I generate a report in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, report

I'd like to know of any tools to generate a report in wpf.

What I want to do is to generate the report and export it immediately to a pdf, csv or just print it. I don't want the client to be able to "adjust" the report from within my application. Also the report tool should give me lots of freedom, since I'm geerating reports from a datagrid that is constantly changing, according to the user's commands (in other words .. it's dynamic)

Does anyone know of any tools that allow me to do that (preferably an open source tool, but I'm not tied to it being open source)?

Comment: Well, you could use the builtin reporting services tools (maybe a SSRS report that runs within the Microsoft Reporting Services). Printing and exporting can be done as described in my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9717686/printing-a-report-server-side-and-silently/9717894#9717894

Comment: I don't follow this question.  Are you asking how to format data into a report that you've already been able to render on-screen?  You say you don't want to let the user adjust the report, but then in the next sentence you say that the report is generated from constantly changing data, *based on user's commands*.

Comment: This needs a lot more information or it is going to get voted down.  PDF is not easy to write to.  FlowDocument or XPS are more .NET friendly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Crystal Reports, just like we use it in WinForms.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with crystal reports, [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/74499/Crystal-Report-in-WPF) may be useful to you. Otherwise you could always use xslt and xml

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479390/microsoft-reporting-vs-xml-xslt) makes a a compelling arguement for micrsoft or third party reporting compared to xslt "hand made" reports.

Edit: As a first go, it may be adviseable to use the crystal report creation wizard

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Reporting isn't specific to WPF.  You can look at Crystal Reports, SSRS Reports (both server *.rdl and client embedded *.rdlc), or tools from companies like DevExpress' XtraReports.

The +1 for using [SSRS Reports](http://www.mono-project.com/Libraries#Reporting) is that there appears to be a Mono project that will allow you to render them, so you're not tied 100% to the Microsoft server stack, if you have that requirement.  Look at FYI Reporting from the provided link.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options here.

You can print a visual to pdf using a virtual printer: http://www.pdfforge.org/products/pdfcreator.

There are also XPS to PDF converters.

And, of course, there are numerous WPF based report generators.

You're question is quite clear, so I wasn't sure what exactly you were after.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using ActiveReports to fulfill your reporting needs as ActiveReports has a viewer and end user report designer control which can work quite well in WPF environment.The End user designer control will also allow your end users modify reports at their will.

Regarding the exporting capabilities , ActiveReports will let you export to PDF,Excel,Word,Tiff,Jpeg,Text etc.And lastly activereport will give you the flexibility you are looking for as it can be bound to datasets,XML,OLedbm,sql,Excel sheets, text,array, objects etc ..

You can visit these links to know more how ActiveReports works on WPF:
http://blogs.gcpowertools.co.in/2011/11/how-to-view-report-created-using-active.html

http://blogs.gcpowertools.co.in/2011/08/how-to-host-active-reports-end-user.html